# python docx align both left and right on same line

Tags: python, alignment, docx, python-docx

This is my first question on SO and would like to thank you all in advance for any help. I'm pretty new to python, python-docx and programming in general. I am working on a GUI program (using PyQt) to generate a contract in docx format. I have most things working, but here is the problem I am having. I need to align text both left and right on the same line. In word, I believe this is done by changing to a right indent and hitting tab, then adding the text. However, I cannot figure out how to do this in python-docx. I tried:

```
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.add_run('SOME TEXT')
paragraph.alignment = 0
paragraph.add_run('SOME OTHER TEXT')
paragraph.alignment = 2
```

but this didn't work. I tried some other ideas per the documentation, like enum WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT, but nothing worked.

Is this possible to do in python-docx (im using version 0.8.5)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: From what I know of docx, I don't think it has the capability to do what you want (which is a right aligned tab in a left aligned paragraph).  However, you can definitely still do this programatically, you'll just have to delve into coms a bit

Comment: I was really hoping that wouldnt be the case...being a newb to this stuff I was really hoping to avoid COM and Win32 API at this stage for such a simple little program....appreciate your answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution, but...

I am also generating contracts with python-docx and came across this same issue.  Until the [right-aligned tab stop feature](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/157) is added, my workaround is to format the line as a table, using a custom table style.

- First, open a document ('custom_styles.docx') and add a table with 1 row and 2 columns.
- Select the table and add a new table style ('CustomTable'), where the first column is left-aligned and the last column is right-aligned.  (I also made the borders invisible by setting them to 'none' or coloring them white.)
- Delete the table and save the document, which will give you an empty document with the new 'CustomTable' style.

The following should work for creating a line that appears to be both left-aligned and right-aligned:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('custom_styles.docx')
table = document.add_table(1, 2, style='CustomTable')
table.cell(0,0).text = 'Left Text'
table.cell(0,1).text = 'Right Text'
document.save('new_document_name.docx')
```

The trickiest part for me was figuring out how to create the table style in Word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..after having issues building the program (read a bunch of people having issues building the docx module specifically) I gave up and started learning C# lol..I rewrote the program using a template and replacing variables I created in the word document instead of using a module to build the document for me..not perfect but it worked (more or less)..however, I will mark your answer as the most helpful since it seems like a good work-around until the feature is implemented..thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a paragraph that is *fully justified*, meaning it lines up with the margins on both the left and right side, that is done with the `Paragraph.alignment` property:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('A paragraph of text ..')
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
```

If you're looking to establish a right-aligned tab stop, that's not supported yet in `python-docx`. You can add a feature request on the GitHub issues list here: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues

A good issue name would be "feature: tab stops".

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify, basically the program is made to create a contract in docx format, so I need to have underscore lines where people can sign the contracts on each side of the document, on the same line. Hope that makes sense. Seems like that would probably be the tab stops you mentioned, and I will probably request that feature. For now I will probably have to deal with adding tabs (\t) to my runs and have to manually fix the formatting after the docx is created. Thanks again for your help though!