# python-doxc table cell align adds a new line

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to right align the text inside a table cell of a **Word** document created with **python-docx**. I followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736364/docx-center-text-in-table-cells), but the problem with it is that a new line is added inside de cell before the text, so the vertical alignment is broken.

This is the code without the right alignment setting:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells

hdr_cells[0].width = Inches(0.1)
hdr_cells[1].width = Inches(10)
hdr_cells[2].width = Inches(1)
hdr_cells[3].width = Inches(1)

for entry in context['invoices']['entries']:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(entry['amount'])
    row_cells[1].text = entry['line']
    row_cells[2].text = entry['unit_price_label']
    row_cells[3].text = entry['subtotal']
```

And this is the resulting document:
[image]

This is the code with the right alignment setting:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells

hdr_cells[0].width = Inches(0.1)
hdr_cells[1].width = Inches(10)
hdr_cells[2].width = Inches(1)
hdr_cells[3].width = Inches(1)

for entry in context['invoices']['entries']:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(entry['amount'])
    row_cells[1].text = entry['line']
    row_cells[2].add_paragraph(entry['unit_price_label']).alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
    row_cells[3].add_paragraph(entry['subtotal']).alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

And the resulting document:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this carriage return when right aligning table cells with **python-docx**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, use

```
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

A table cell must always include at least one paragraph; this is prescribed by the ISO 29500 spec (and makes sense once you look into it deeply enough).

In accordance with this requirement, a new (and empty) cell contains a single empty paragraph. If you call `.add_paragraph()` on an empty cell, then you end up with *two* paragraphs.

So the secret to avoiding extra paragraphs is to start by using the one you already have. Only if you need more than one paragraph do you call `.add_paragraph()`.

The single existing paragraph is accessed as `cell.paragraphs[0]` and can be manipulated the same way as any other paragraph in `python-docx`