# How to change alignment of cell text in MS Word table without "paragraph" object

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a MS Word "template" file that I am opening, modifying with new data from various sources, and then saving as a new file. I have multiple tables in the template document which are appropriately styled, including centered text inside of table cells.

Having some familiarity with the python-docx module, I am able to alter the table's data easily, by assigning new values to `cell.text`. However, whenever I assign `cell.text` a new value, the new data is no longer centered, but is instead left-justified.

I have browsed several similar questions, but all of the answers seem to involve modifying paragraph objects. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736364/docx-center-text-in-table-cells) post was helpful and provided a quick POC, but also doesn't deal with `cells`, but instead adding `paragraphs` to tables. However, it was helpful seeing that `paragraph` objects have an `alignment` attribute.

```py
# Example table
table = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=2)
row = table.add_row().cells

p=row[0].add_paragraph('center justified text')
p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

p.alignment
>>> 1
```

For my current case, I noticed that `cells` do not have the `alignment` attribute. I then tried to modify the paragraph objects, but nothing changes.

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
doc = Document(BASE_DOC)

# test table, row, and cell
table = doc.tables[1]
row = table.rows[4]
cells = row.cells
cells[0].alignment
>>> AttributeError: '_Cell' object has no attribute 'alignment'

# attempt to modify paragraph alignment in table cells
for col in table.columns:
    for cell in col.cells:
        for par in cell.paragraphs:
            par.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

doc.save(NEW_DOC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to `_Cell.text` is a convenient and compact way to set the contents of a cell to a known state. To do this, `_Cell.text` removes *all* content from the cell and then adds a single paragraph containing a single run containing the text you specified.

Because run and paragraph formatting is *part* of the run or paragraph it formats, all run formatting and all paragraph formatting disappears when you assign to `_Cell.text`. This is part of the "setting to known state" bit.

If you apply your paragraph centering *after* assigning to `_Cell.text`, you will see it reflected in the output.

Alternatively, you would avoid assigning to `_Cell.text` and navigate the existing paragraphs and runs yourself.

Comment: Thanks @scnany. I was able to figure this out shortly before you commented, actually. In this case, using `cells[0].paragraphs[0].text = 'new info'` was the solution (preserved/applied the existing style and formatting) as opposed to just `cells[0].text = 'new info'`. I'm still working on obtaining a better understanding of the Word Doc model and all of the relevant objects.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ahmed and glad you got it working. Don't neglect to accept this answer if it answers your question, that's how the StackOverflow economy works :)